# How to export SVG without lines, polylines and polygons?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, path

In illustrator I have made a complex shape and when I export it I get this (I copied a bit of this, its not the entire image as its about 700 lines :P )

```
<line class="st10" x1="784.9" y1="419.6" x2="1033.5" y2="422.6"/>
<polyline class="st10" points="1026.2,536.3 1026.2,437.3 1388.7,378.4   "/>
<polyline class="st10" points="1033.5,435.6 1033.5,398.2 1080.4,387 1390.4,312.4    "/>
<line class="st10" x1="1080.2" y1="428.6" x2="1080.4" y2="387"/>
<line class="st10" x1="1139.7" y1="418.9" x2="1139.7" y2="372.7"/>
<line class="st10" x1="1215.8" y1="406.5" x2="1215.8" y2="354.4"/>
<line class="st10" x1="1316.9" y1="390" x2="1316.9" y2="330"/>
<path class="st10" d="M1388.6,500c-17.5-3-348.2,1.5-348.2,1.5v-44.4l348.2-36.4"/>
<line class="st10" x1="1053.3" y1="455.8" x2="1053.3" y2="501.2"/>
```

and some paths.  How can I export just as paths?  I want sections so I do not require the entire vector to be a path.  It also exports the css styles, how do I to turn these off?

Comment: I've never seen the line thing before in any of my SVGs, but my best guess would be that you need to expand the appearance of any lines that you have a stroke applied to inside Illustrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy. The only thing you need is to convert those primitives (polygons, lines, etc) from paths into *compound paths* by clicking <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win.

I wouldn't recommend to expand the appearance because in this case you will lose an ability to change a stroke width in SVG.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: to click cmd + 8 doesn't work for me, unfortunately.
Is it needed to click every single polygon with cmd+8?