# How to force paths instead polygons when exporting images as svg?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I there a way to force Illustrator to use paths instead polygons when exporting as svg?

Here is how my svg code looks like:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px"
     width="581.098px" height="103.456px"
     viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 581.098 103.456"
     enable-background="new -0.5 -0.5 581.098 103.456"
     xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M211.29,287.61a10.32,10.32,0,1,1,7.22,2.95,9.82,9.82,0,0,1-7.22-2.95" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
    <polygon points="58.27 20.55 40.65 20.55 20.97 74.77 38.24 74.77 58.27 20.55"/>
    <path d="M314.08,307.06a10.31,10.31,0,1,1-7.22-2.95,9.81,9.81,0,0,1,7.22,2.95" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
    <polygon points="50.42 74.77 68.03 74.77 87.72 20.55 70.44 20.55 50.42 74.77"/>
    <path d="M352.49,324h-15a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V249.69h15V287.8h0l16.7-17.8h18.91a0,0,0,0,1,0,0l-20.5,21.81h0L388.94,324a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H371.12l-13.71-20.61h0l-4.9,5.1h0V324S352.5,324,352.49,324Z" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
    <path d="M423.54,283.67q-6.71,0-10,4.76T410.22,301v23.32h-15V270.46h15v7.1a25.28,25.28,0,0,1,7.26-5.6,19.75,19.75,0,0,1,8.86-2.41l.1,14.12Z" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
    <path d="M487.71,297.39a26.6,26.6,0,0,1-8.11,19.72q-8.12,8-20.38,8t-20.37-8a28.09,28.09,0,0,1,0-39.49q8.11-8.07,20.37-8.07t20.38,8.07a26.77,26.77,0,0,1,8.11,19.77m-41.85,0a15.42,15.42,0,0,0,3.75,10.76,13.19,13.19,0,0,0,19.23,0,15.42,15.42,0,0,0,3.75-10.76,15.63,15.63,0,0,0-3.75-10.81,13.08,13.08,0,0,0-19.23,0,15.63,15.63,0,0,0-3.75,10.81" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
    <polygon points="314.52 74.65 299 74.65 280.67 20.78 296.19 20.78 306.71 53.32 317.22 20.78 331.74 20.78 342.25 53.32 352.77 20.78 368.38 20.78 350.06 74.65 334.44 74.65 324.53 45.31 314.52 74.65"/>
    <path d="M598.2,294.29v30h-15V270.46h15v6q6.81-6.9,15.32-6.91a19,19,0,0,1,14.27,6q5.75,6,5.75,16v32.74h-15V293.89q0-12.42-9.11-12.42a11,11,0,0,0-7.86,3.25q-3.34,3.25-3.35,9.57" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to replace polygons by paths?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/79429/120647) that already has an answer.

However there is an online tool: Codepen [*SVG Polygon/Polyline to Path Converter*](https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/pen/GZwgzV),

Here the solution of your SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px"
 width="581.098px" height="103.456px"
 viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 581.098 103.456"
 enable-background="new -0.5 -0.5 581.098 103.456"
 xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M211.29,287.61a10.32,10.32,0,1,1,7.22,2.95,9.82,9.82,0,0,1-7.22-2.95" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
<path d="M58.27 20.55 40.65 20.55 20.97 74.77 38.24 74.77 58.27 20.55z"/>
<path d="M314.08,307.06a10.31,10.31,0,1,1-7.22-2.95,9.81,9.81,0,0,1,7.22,2.95" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
<path d="M50.42 74.77 68.03 74.77 87.72 20.55 70.44 20.55 50.42 74.77z"/>
<path d="M352.49,324h-15a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V249.69h15V287.8h0l16.7-17.8h18.91a0,0,0,0,1,0,0l-20.5,21.81h0L388.94,324a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H371.12l-13.71-20.61h0l-4.9,5.1h0V324S352.5,324,352.49,324Z" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
<path d="M423.54,283.67q-6.71,0-10,4.76T410.22,301v23.32h-15V270.46h15v7.1a25.28,25.28,0,0,1,7.26-5.6,19.75,19.75,0,0,1,8.86-2.41l.1,14.12Z" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
<path d="M487.71,297.39a26.6,26.6,0,0,1-8.11,19.72q-8.12,8-20.38,8t-20.37-8a28.09,28.09,0,0,1,0-39.49q8.11-8.07,20.37-8.07t20.38,8.07a26.77,26.77,0,0,1,8.11,19.77m-41.85,0a15.42,15.42,0,0,0,3.75,10.76,13.19,13.19,0,0,0,19.23,0,15.42,15.42,0,0,0,3.75-10.76,15.63,15.63,0,0,0-3.75-10.81,13.08,13.08,0,0,0-19.23,0,15.63,15.63,0,0,0-3.75,10.81" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
<path d="M314.52 74.65 299 74.65 280.67 20.78 296.19 20.78 306.71 53.32 317.22 20.78 331.74 20.78 342.25 53.32 352.77 20.78 368.38 20.78 350.06 74.65 334.44 74.65 324.53 45.31 314.52 74.65z"/>
<path d="M598.2,294.29v30h-15V270.46h15v6q6.81-6.9,15.32-6.91a19,19,0,0,1,14.27,6q5.75,6,5.75,16v32.74h-15V293.89q0-12.42-9.11-12.42a11,11,0,0,0-7.86,3.25q-3.34,3.25-3.35,9.57" transform="translate(-208.35 -249.68)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: if it's a duplicate then just flag it to close.